# angular login with $q

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular-ui-router

My Code:

[image]

Error:

[image]

when I try login I have error

Can you tell me what I do wrong and show how it's must look like.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! 
Can you provide please the part of your code that is not working as a text and not as a picture ?

Comment: start from 
function login(email,password){......}
and then Auth.login